# Constructing PDA with either one state or two states

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar

If $L$ is a *context-free language* and $\epsilon  \notin L $, how do you show that there exists a PDA that accepts the language by *final state* such that it has ***not more than two states*** and ***makes no $\epsilon$-moves*** ?

Comment: In what form is the language given to you?

Comment: @TaraB : Hey, thanks for the question. I just edited the post accordingly. You're only required to prove that there exists such an automaton.

Comment: Ah, right.  That renders my question irrelevant!  It also means I know how to give a hint now.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Take a context-free grammar in Chomsky normal form for $L$ and think about how you might be able to use this to construct the PDA in question.  (You can use the stack to perform the derivations, essentially.)

Comment: Wouldn't Greibach Normal form make more sense?

Comment: Yes, it would.  Sorry, I hadn't thought through the part about no $\epsilon$-transitions properly.